# Can not generate Date and Time on Website using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a date and time to the footer of my page. I tried everything and can generate the date a time.

```js
 function currentDateTime() {
        var x = new Date()
        var x1=x.getMonth() + 1+ "/" + x.getDate() + "/" + x.getFullYear(); 
        x1 = x1 + " - " +  x.getHours( )+ ":" +  x.getMinutes() + ":" +  x.getSeconds();
        document.getElementById('currentDateTime').innerHTML = x1;
        currentDateTime();
         }
```

```html
 <footer>
            <a href="/project4/policy.html">Policy and Terms</a>
            <a href="/project4/FAQ.html">FAQ</a> 
            <p><span id="currentDateTime"> </span></p>
 </footer>
```

Comment: You never call `currentDateTime();` *outside* the function itself. And you shouldn't really call it inside the function, as it would lead to infinite recursion. Either move `currentDateTime();` outside in order to call it once or just remove it and add `setInterval(currentDateTime, 1000)` outside to update it every second (or whatever time delay you want).

Answer (score 2):

You have to call your function `currentDateTime()` outside of itself

```js
function currentDateTime() {
        var x = new Date()
        var x1=x.getMonth() + 1+ "/" + x.getDate() + "/" + x.getFullYear(); 
        x1 = x1 + " - " +  x.getHours( )+ ":" +  x.getMinutes() + ":" +  x.getSeconds();
        document.getElementById('currentDateTime').innerHTML = x1;
         }
        currentDateTime();
```

```html
<footer>
            <a href="/project4/policy.html">Policy and Terms</a>
            <a href="/project4/FAQ.html">FAQ</a> 
            <p><span id="currentDateTime"> </span></p>
 </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

you call function inside it

```js
function currentDateTime() {
        var x = new Date()
        var x1= x.getMonth() + 1+ "/" + x.getDate() + "/" + x.getFullYear(); 
        x1 = x1 + " - " +  x.getHours( )+ ":" +  x.getMinutes() + ":" +  x.getSeconds();
        document.getElementById('currentDateTime').innerHTML = x1;
        
         }

currentDateTime();
```